# Divs out of position in IE and firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

For a school assignment I was required to redesign a website for a buisness.

I had only ever mucked around with css/html before and this is the first time I had written it for a full website.

The issue I am facing is the positioning of 3 divs is correct in google chrome, but in IE and firefox the divs are incorrectly positioned.

http://letsmine.info/mnpctech/index.html they are the twitter, facebook and checkout symbols on the right of the menu bar.

As this is the first time I have written CSS and HTML I presume this is a silly mistake and I am hoping that you can guide me into the right direction.

Also on the store page I need to layout the products with a picture and name like they are here http://www.mnpctech.com/MnpctechBilletFanGrill.html . Should I create a table and just put the images and title in there? just looking for some advice.

Comment: I believe you that the social icons are incorrectly positioned... but what is the "correct" way you'd like them?

Comment: Have you [checked your html for errors?](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Always remember that Firefox will show what you wrote while IE will make things up as it goes along. Never, ever trust IE to do anything right. It's the worst browser on the planet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following properties to #checkout, #facebook and #twitter:

```
display: inline-block;
float: right;
```

and remove the following properties from each one:

```
position: relative;
left: 980px;
top: -49px;
```

The page should then display properly in all browsers.

Make sure that you use floats and know your way around the "display" property well for positioning, I always try to stay away from relative positioning as it's a bit unreliable.